# How to create a postive and negative sequence

Tags: r, sequence

I'm currently working on r to bring myself upto scratch.
Trying to create a sequence which is

(-10,10,100,100,1000,1000)

My first question is how do I create a sequence that alternates between positive and negative

Secondly how do I create a sequence that multiplies itself by 10 every x amount of numbers.

Comment: The question is not clear. Could you provide what is the output you expect on an example ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `rep` and `cumprod` *creating a sequence that multiplies itself by 10* and multiply with `c(-1,1)` to *alternates between positive and negative*:

```
rep(cumprod(rep(10, 3)), each=2) * c(-1, 1)
#[1]   -10    10  -100   100 -1000  1000
```

Answer (score 5):

Another idea can be,

```
rep(10^seq(3), each = 2) * c(-1, 1)
#[1]   -10    10  -100   100 -1000  1000
```

Just adding a benchmark. Turns out, `cumprod` is fast

```
microbenchmark(sotos = rep(10 ^ seq(30), each = 2) * c(-1, 1), 
               GKi = rep(cumprod(rep(10, 30)), each = 2) * c(-1, 1))
```

> ```
> Unit: microseconds
>   expr   min    lq    mean median    uq    max neval
>  sotos 6.911 7.212 7.83658  7.512 7.513 30.348   100
>    GKi 1.502 1.803 2.03470  1.804 2.104 11.118   100
> ```